# decode in php data that was stored in MySQL using AES_ENCODE

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, aes

I have some legacy data in a database that was stored using the built-in (MySQL) AES_ENCODE function, with a plaintext key.

According to the MySQL docs, AES_ENCODE uses 128 bit encryption, but it's not clear what mode (CBC or ECB), and it's not mentioned how it generates an I-V (my guess is it can't unless it stores this with the encrypted data).  Apparently ECB mode doesn't require an I-V.

Does anyone know if it's possible to decrypt the raw encrypted data outside of MySQL?  E.g. what settings would I use for openssl_decrypt for this. I've tried a fair few iterations now.

Thanks

Comment: *"I've tried a fair few iterations now"* - Cool, show us what you've tried.

Comment: none worked.  All gave me null back. using AES_128_ECB which according to docs is what they use.  I wonder if it's the format of the crypto text, or key.

Comment: I just found this tho - maybe the answer, looks like mySQL munges the key to make it 16 bytes long with basic xor.  https://info.michael-simons.eu/2011/07/18/mysql-compatible-aes-encryption-decryption-in-java/

Comment: show us the code please